# separate IDEE process from JVM process in inttellij-idea

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm

In Eclipse I can separate the jvm process from the Eclipse process.
When I separate process the jvm process is about 700MB and the eclipse process is lesser than that.
Before the separation I had an unique big and slow process.
I seen this site for the eclipse issues:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Can I do the same thing in Intellij-idea???

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such way. As far as I understand, the Eclipse launcher does allow you to start the IDE in a separate VM, but I don't see how exactly it could be beneficial. The Eclipse launcher does not do any work; all the work is still done in the IDE process which does not get singnificantly smaller from not having the launcher in it.